# Which version of Chrome am I using?

Tags: google-chrome

How do I know which version of Google Chrome I'm using on Windows? I installed Chrome for work from:
https://www.google.ca/work/chrome/browser/

But the version number is exactly the same as the normal one.  What is different that can prove I'm using the enterprise version of Chrome from the above URL?

Comment: maybe check navigate to: chrome://version/ I don't know if there are indications there or not as I do not have enterprise chrome

Answer (score 1):

Or just do this:

chrome://version